# Weird Bayes Rule Application, Wanted Effect is Also a Condition

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I'm a bit confused after seeing this show up in my textbook.
[image]

I've never really seen an application of Baye's Rule like this one - sorry for the lack of specificity in the question, but I don't really know what I should be asking. How do I interpret this? I'm more used to something like:

$$p(w | A, B \propto p(A, B|w)p(w) $$

where A, B appear as the same thing.

**EDIT** More Context.

This is in the context of Bayesian Linear Regression. The author is explaining how we can come to the same optimal answer for Linear Regression from a Bayesian standpoint. w is the set of weights in linear regression, X is a design matrix of examples ${x_1, x_2.... x_m}$.

We assume that the prior probability distribution of possible values of the weights vector $w$ follow some sort of Gaussian distribution, and we also assume that $p(y| X, w)$ follows a gaussian distribution as well, where the mean $\mu$ is equal to $Xw$ and the variance is the identity matrix $I$.

Textbook pages I am referring to are [HERE](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html), at pages 135-136.

Could someone explain how this is possible and why it makes sense?
Thanks,
A

Comment: Can you please provide the context for this formula? There are probably some independence assumptions in the textbook that can help us give a more precise answer.

Comment: sorry! added more clarification on the context in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding the context! You're right that this isn't a typical form of Bayes's rule. It's true if we make a fairly natural independence assumption.

It's common to write Bayes's rule as
$$p(B \mid A) \propto p(A \mid B) p(B)\text{.}$$

You can also write this [conditioned on a third variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Generalizations):
$$p(B \mid A, C) \propto p(A \mid B, C) p(B \mid C)\text{.}$$

Using the variables from your regression model, we can write

$$p(w \mid y, X) \propto p(y \mid w, X) p(w \mid X)\text{.}$$

This is the equation from the textbook, except for the last term. We need $p(w \mid X)$ to equal $p(w)$ for the textbook equation to hold true. But we typically *do* make this independence assumption: our initial belief about the weights $w$ of the model doesn't depend on the covariates $X$.

---

For people looking this up later, the question is about equation (5.74) in *Deep Learning* by Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville.